# What is the fastest method for autonomous transaction in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, clr

I am trying to simulate **autonomous transaction** in **SQL Server**, but the problem is, that using **CLR DLL procedure** (that is using different session) slows down the performance about 5 times.

To be clear:
Let's assume that in one transaction I am calling procedure for every of 100k rows in table, which gives 100k proc calls in one transaction. If any of this procedure fails, I want to rollback the entire transaction (AFTER all procedures calls), but I need to keep logs from the procedures that fails (in case of failure, insert to ErrorLog table).

---

The problem is, that in such case, I perform 100k connections, and it cost in terms of performance.
Using **table variable** is not a solution, because I am not able to control every transaction (some are controlled by frontend), using Loopback (to the same server) is not recommended in production (from what I read), so the solution was to use CLR for different session purpose.

---

Is there any solution to maybe create altered session for every session, and use that session for all those insert instead of creating new connection every time, or is my understanding of using CLR wrong, and it must open new connection every time. (From what I read, context_session uses the same session from what it was called, so in case of rollback, it will delete my logs from ErrorLog table).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `"SAVE TRAN XXXX"` in the procedure and a `"ROLLBACK TRAN XXXX"` where an exception occurs. The Insert into the ERRORLOG table should be after the `"ROLLBACK TRAN XXXX` in the Procedure not to be rolled back.

Hope this helps...